# Recoger datos de un input e insertarlos en otro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo mi formulario:

```
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="nombre">

<input type="text" name="" plaholder="apellidos">

<select>
<option>seleccion 1</option>
<option>seleccion 2</option>
<option>seleccion 3<option>
</select>
```

quiero que todos los datos introducidos en estos campos sean introducidos todos también en un textarea:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

¿cómo lo puedo hacer usando jquery o javascript?

Comment: ¿ Cómo debería ser el resultado final ? podrias colocar un ejemplo.

Comment: Simplemente que todo el texto ingresado en los input sea agregado al textarea, en el value obviamente para que esa información también se envíe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas agregarles un `id` para poder tomar el valor de cada **input** y de cada **select** podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
function agregar(){

var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
var apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
var sexo = document.getElementById('sexo').value;
var textarea = document.getElementById('texto');

if(nombre == '' || apellido == '' || sexo == ''){
alert('todos los campos son obligatorios');
}else{

textarea.innerHTML = nombre+','+apellido+','+sexo;
}





}
```

```html
Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre" required>
Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido" required>

Sexo: <select id="sexo" required>
<option value="">Selecciona</option>
<option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
<option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>

</select>
<br>
<br>
<button id="agregar" type="submit" onclick="agregar()">Agregar info</button>
<br>
<textarea id="texto" rows="5" width="5%"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas identificar cada input, Select, etc. con un ID clase, etc. Luego desde el javascript obtienes la data ingresada en casa uno y lo guardas ya sea en un string o array como te funcione mejor. Luego está data la seteas en el textarea.

```
// use to select with DOM element.
var value = $("input").val();

// use the id to select the element.
var value = $("#txt_name").val();

// use type="text" with input to select the element
var value = $("input:text").val();


// use to add "text content" to the DOM element.
$("input").val(value);

// use the id to add "text content" to the element.
$("#txt_name").val(value);

// use type="text" with input to add "text content" to the element
$("input:text").val(value)
```

Comment: Pero explica bien porque no entiendo nada.  Como queda el código construido?

Comment: @Header90 Te estoy dando la información necesaria para hacer resolver tu duda, el uso exacto se lo darás cuando lo implementes.

Answer (score 1):

**Buena tarde, te propongo la misma solución, pero con Jquery, que a mi parecer simplifica más el código.**

Lo interesnte de Jquery es la forma de acceder a los elementos, en este caso como manejamos el atributo 'id', accedemos mediante un **#** y **el nombre de ese id**, de esta forma: **$('#nombreId');** y **.val()**, simplemente obtiene el valor de los input.

Espero te ayude en algo.

```js
//Asociamos evento click al botón 'Obtener Datos'
$('#jsObtainedData').on('click', ()=>{
  //Obtenemos los respectivos valores de los input y el select
  let valueName = $('#jsNombre').val()+', ';
  let valueApellido = $('#jsApellidos').val()+', ';
  let valueSelect = $('#jsSelect').val();
  
  //Cargamos al textarea los valores anteriores con .text()
  $('#jsTextarea').text(valueName+valueApellido+valueSelect);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="jsNombre" placeholder="nombre"><br>
<input type="text" id="jsApellidos" placeholder="apellidos"><br>
<select id="jsSelect">
<option>Seleccion 1</option>
<option>Seleccion 2</option>
<option>Seleccion 3<option>
</select><br><br><br>

<button id="jsObtainedData">Obtener Datos</button><br>
<textarea id="jsTextarea"></textarea>
```